# elegant way to File.read assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have the following code

```
module EmailHelper
  def email_image_tag(image, **options)
    attachments.inline[image] = File.read(image_path(image))
    image_tag attachments[image].url, **options
  end
end
```

In production this references the correct image with hash, because the image asset is precompiled, however in development this throws a file read exception.

Is there an elegant way to do a File.read without having to check on if Rails.env.development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest misconception here was that I thought I should point to a digested asset, forgetting that these are meant to be served and not read as a file. Therefore the file can be perfectly loaded from the asset map. I solved the above question as follows:

```
module MailHelper
  def mail_image_tag(image, **options)
    path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', image)

    attachments.inline[image] = File.read(path)
    image_tag attachments[image].url, **options
  end
end
```